# Bloomberg data - Correlation Matrix

Tags: correlation, bloomberg

Am new to python coding. I'm trying to import Historical data from the Bloomberg to run some tests on correlations over a range of different indices available. Do you guys have any suggestions on how I can import the data and build a correlation matrix for such?

```
Correlation 
Description                         Bloomberg Ticker
MSCI Bangladesh IMI Net TR USD          M1BDIM
MSCI India Net TR USD                   M1IN
MSCI EM Asia Healthcare Net TR USD  M1MS0HC
MSCI EM Asia Info Tech Net TR USD   M1MS0IT
MSCI Philippines USD Net TR         M1PH
MSCI Pakistan USD Net TR            M1PK
MSCI Pakistan IMI Net TR USD            M1PKIM
MSCI AC Asia ex Japan Net TR USD    MXASJ
MSCI Thailand USD Net TR            MXTH
MSCI Japan Net TR Small Cap USD         NCUAJN
MSCI Singapore SGD Net TR           NDDLSG
MSCI Hong Kong USD Net TR           NDDUHK
MSCI Japan Net TR USD                   NDDUJN
MSCI Malaysia USD Net TR            NDDUMAF
MSCI SingaporeUSD Net TR            NDDUSG
MSCI China USD Net TR                   NDEUCHF
MSCI Korea USD Net TR                   NDEUSKO
```

Answer (score 0):

For data analysis in python you should look at the `pandas` library. Correlation documentation is available [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html). You can download data from Bloomberg using `pdblp`, there is information about the project [here](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/pdblp) (Disclaimer: I am the author of `pdblp`). The relevant method is `bdh()`.

A simple example of calculating correlation would be

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(100,2))
In [3]: df.corr()
Out[3]: 
          0         1
0  1.000000 -0.012137
1 -0.012137  1.000000
```

A simple example to pull historical data from Bloomberg with `pdblp` is

```
In [1]: import pdblp
In [2]: con = pdblp.BCon()
In [3]: con.start()
In [4]: df = con.bdh('SPY US Equity', 'PX_LAST', '20150629', '20150630')
```